# Add transition on window resize

Tags: jquery, resize, css-transitions, window-resize

I am trying to create responsive layout for my website.

This is what i am trying to do-

[image]

While i am re-sizing window , window's width is reducing by 100 pixels only from right side of document. I want it to be happen on all sides of this box.

At the same time when i am re-sizing window i want to add transitions on this block. 
But transition works with properties assigned within css.

How can i add transitions with window size ?

**css-**

```
.box
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    position:absolute;
}
.box-narrow
{
    -webkit-transition:all .6s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

**jQuery-**

```
$(function(){
   var windowwi=$(window).width();
windowwi-=100;
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        $('.box').width(windowwi);
        $('.box').addClass(
    });
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GUbYg/)

Answer (score 2):

Your jquery code contain an error, plus you don't need to play with the classes, just because when you assign a transition on a element the browser to the transition whenever the element change.

So this is your jquery code:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('resize',function(){

   var windowwi=$(window).width();
        windowwi-=100;
        $('.box').width(windowwi);
    });
});
```

Note that i put the `windowwi` variable on the 'resize' event function, so you can have the size of the window when is resized.
and this is the css:

```
.box
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition:all .6s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GUbYg/1/)